# pseudo-element :first-child not being picked up

Tags: css

Given the following snippet, I would expect the div containing "Award 1" to have a red background colour. Can someone explain to me why it does not? The first item should have a border top.

```css
.item-wrap:first-child .item {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row awards">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="no-border">Awards</h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Award 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Award 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try just .item-wrap:first-child without the :(.

Comment: just hangover from some retries; post now as it should be and still not womm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

:first-child (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child)

In your example you are attempting to select an element with the class `.item` which resides in a parent with the class `.item-wrap` which itself is the first child of its parent (in this case `.awards`). As `.item-wrap` is not the first child of `.awards` it does not match.

Given your markup the following rule should fit your needs:

```css
.awards :first-child + .item-wrap .item:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row awards">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="no-border">Awards</h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Award 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Award 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will select an element with the class `.item` which is the first child of its parent `.item-wrap` which is immediately preceded by the first child that belongs to the element with the class `.awards`.

Comment: Ah, so the rule I've specified is saying "first child and has class", not "first child with this class"? Not how I'd understood it..

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap child elements with a parent div like this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="row awards">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="no-border">Awards</h2> 
  </div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
        <div class="item">Award 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
        <div class="item">Award 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item-wrap:first-child .item {
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjJBQL

Comment: This works. But I'm in the dark as to why since they already had a parent...this seems like a hack (but presumably is not)

Comment: the problem is every child doesn't have .item-wrap  :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item-wrap:nth-child(2){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row awards">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
<h2 class="no-border">Awards</h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
<div class="item">Award 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
<div class="item">Award 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there was no css2 tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item:first-child{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row awards">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="no-border">Awards</h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Award 1</div>
    <div class="item">Award 1a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Award 2</div>
    <div class="item">Award 2a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Place the selector on the child, not the parent (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNQamR):

```
.item:first-child{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm after. I want a border-top on the first wrapper, which is a bootsrap cell, spanning 100%. Question updated.